# Get current active child component in Angular 6

Tags: angular, angular6, angular-activatedroute

I'm using `Angular 6`.

I have created a deep routing in my application where `app.module` a declaration with component `AdminLayout`

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    AdminLayoutComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot([]),
    ComponentsModule,
  ]
});
```

and further `AdminLayoutComponent` is a module which imports all other modules inside it.

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    ...
    DashboardModule
  ],
  declarations: []
})
export class AdminLayoutModule { }
```

**ComponentsModule** is imported in **AppModule** in which I want to get the currently active component or the URL.

So, Inside a component of **ComponentsModule**, I'm doing it like this:

```
constructor(
  private route: ActivatedRoute
) { }

ngOnInit() {
  console.log(this.route);
}
```

which consoles like

[image]

Here, it has the `component > name` as **AdminLayoutComponent** whereas I have loaded **DashboardComponent**.

**How can I get the currently active component name or the URL?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use Router service to get current url , the url change in every navigation so you can 
subscribe to route events to keep update

```
import {  Router } from '@angular/router';
```

component

```
constructor( private _router: Router,) { ...}

ngOnInit() {
   this.router.events.subscribe(e => {
      if (e instanceof NavigationStart) {
        console.log(e.url);
        console.log(this.router.routerState.root.snapshot.firstChild); // active component
        console.log(this.router.routerState.root.snapshot.data); // route data
        console.log(this.router.routerState.root.snapshot.routeConfig); // routes list
      }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public ngOnInit() {
  this.helloChild()
  this.router.events.subscribe((event) => {
    if (event instanceof NavigationEnd) {
      this.helloChild()
    }
  })
}

private helloChild() {
  const firstChild = this.route.snapshot.firstChild
  console.log('firstChild', firstChild)
}
```